# React: Insert value at cursor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need to add a value (from the dropdown), this will be added in the input field 'at the position of the cursor':

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [cur, setCur] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  const [dropVal, setDropVal] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
    // gives cursor index 
    // this only shows cursor position if user types 
    // I need to track the position of the cursor and add dropVal there
    setCur(e.target.selectionStart); 
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} value={state} />
      <select onChange={(e) => setDropVal(e.target.value)} >
        <option>ONE</option>
        <option>TWO</option>
      </select>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried this, which is incomplete, couldn't find a way to implement it anywhere.
Would appreciate the help, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties on an input field.

Basically, you can attach an `onBlur` listener on your input field and inside it you can access the `selectionStart` property and save it in state.

Blur means that the input field has lost its focus (*meaning you have clicked somewhere outside - like on the dropdown in our case*). So once the onBlur is triggered, the `selectionStart` refers to where your cursor was while the input was still in focus.

Later you can use this value to break the string and add whatever you want (option value in this case) at the position of the cursor.

```
const onBlur = (e) => {
    setCur(e.target.selectionStart);
};
```

[Have a look at this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-example-5y5zl)

Comment: Hey Karan. Could you check and tell if this works ?